# AttributeError in DeleteView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm getting the following error whenever I try to delete an object of class `AbstractThing` in a `DeleteView` (e.g. in the admin area):

```
AttributeError: 'OneToOneField' object has no attribute 'model'
```

Relevant models and views:

```
class AbstractThing(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    color = models.CharField(max_length=6)


class ConcreteThing(AbstractThing):

    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='concrete_things')


class ConcreteThingDeleteView(DeleteView):

    model = ConcreteThing
    success_url = "…"


from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    (…)
```

I don't know what's happening since the error message is not specific at all. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='concrete_things').. User should not be surrounded by parenthesis   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='concrete_things')

Comment: I forgot to mention that User refers to a custom user model in the same model file. Therefore, specifying the model as a string should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the incorrect format for referencing the model to create the foreign key to. It should be either `'appname.ModelName'` (using quotes) or just plain `ModelName` if you are importing the model at the top of the same python file.

In your case you probably need `User` instead of `'User'`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that `User` refers to a custom user model in the same model file. Therefore, specifying the model as a string should not be a problem.